# link rel canonical not getting added on mobile view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, nopcommerce

I was working on NopCommerce 2.40 and trying to add link rel="canonical" on page using

```
Html.AddCanonicalUrlParts(categoryUrl);
```

Above code is working on Desktop page bt on on mobile view. Code is getting executed but when I inspect source code cant see any link rel="canonical"

Any Solutios

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.

Needed to add Following to Layout i.e root page

```
@Html.NopCanonicalUrls()
```